# Expand $\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}$ about $z=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I need to expand $\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}$ about $z=1$. I tried substituting 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + 1/5! + 1/6! + 1/7! + ... for $e$ but it doesn't solve the purpose. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Hint : $e^{z-1}=e^z\cdot \frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 5):

Let $z-1=t \implies z=t+1$

Therefore, $\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}$ = $\frac{e^{(t+1)}}{t^2}=\frac{e}{t^2}.e^t$

=$\frac{e}{t^2}[1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\cdots]$

=$e[\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{t}{3!}+\frac{t^2}{4!}+\cdots]$

Now, replacing $t$ by $z-1$,  we get,

$e[(z-1)^{-2}+(z-1)^{-1}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}.(z-1)+\frac{1}{4!}.(z-1)^{2}+\cdots]$

which is the desired expansion.